# Differential Equations/IVP: $\frac{dy}{dt} = 4 - y^3$ and $y(-1)=2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Transform the given initial value problem into an equivalent problem with the initial point at the origin.

$$\cfrac {dy}{dt} = 4 - y^3 \\ y(-1)=2$$

I have no idea about how to solve it.
Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your I.V.P. looks like $y'=f\circ y, y(t_0)=y_0$. This is called an [autonomous differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_%28mathematics%29). Read its [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_%28mathematics%29#Properties).

Let $\varphi$ be a solution to the I.V.P. defined on an interval $I$.

Then $\forall t\in I\left(\varphi '(t)=f(\varphi(t))\right)$ and $\varphi(t_0)=y_0$.

Let $J=\{t-t_0\colon t\in I\}$ and define $\psi \colon J\to \Bbb R, x\mapsto \varphi(x+t_0)$.

Check that $\psi$ is a solution to the I.V.P..

Answer (score 0):

The equation is separable and equivalent to

$$\int \frac{dy}{4-y^3} = t$$

You may carry out the integration by decomposing into partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{4-y^3} = \frac{A}{4^{1/3}-y} + \frac{B y+C}{4^{2/3}+4^{1/3} y+y^2}$$

Solve for $A$, $B$, and $C$.  Then you may integrate each term individually and get $t(y)$.  Invert if possible to get $y(t)$.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is asking for a solution of the differential equation. At least I didn't interpret it that way.

Comment: "I have no idea about how to solve it. Could you please help?" - Admittedly a bit ambiguous, but that's how I interpreted it.

Comment: In any case the answer must be contained in one of our answers.

Comment: I guess the OP answered the question for us.