# Piecewise solutions to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand that the solution to the following is not unique:

$$y'=2ty^{1/3}.$$

However, why does this fact imply that "the solution you obtain via separation of variables must be 'glued' together with the equilibrium solution through piecewise definition"?

For context, I was asked this on an exam recently (the circled and correct equation is above):

> One of the following four equations will require you to "glue" together solutions that you obtain via separation of variables with
>   equilibrium solutions through piecewise definitions. First, circle the
>   equation that requires this approach. Second, justify your answer.
>
> Circle one:

Comment: Apparently, the most concise justification is "the solution is not unique."

Comment: I suggest you try to solve the D.E.. The answer will become apparent.

Comment: @GitGud, I'm not as much struggling with the concept as with how to articulate it

Comment: I understand that. I struggled with that a lot, specially in differential equations. What follows doesn't try to be a full mark answer (because I will consider special cases instead of the general case), but hopefully it will nudge you in the right direction. Let $f$ be a solution to the D.E.. Then, for all $t$ in the domain of $f$, one has $f'(t)=2t\root 3\of{f(t)}$. Now one either has $f$ always null or it isn't zero somewhere. We won't care about the first case for now. If it isn't zero somewhere, that it isn't zero in a whole interval $I$ (due to $f$ being continuous), therefore:

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\forall t\in I\left(\dfrac{f'(t)}{(f(t))^{1/3}}=2t\right)
&\implies \exists C\in \mathbb R\forall t\in I\left(\dfrac{3f(t)^{2/3}}{2}=t^2+C\right)\\
&\implies \exists C\in \mathbb R\forall t\in I\left(f(t)^2=\left(\dfrac 23t^2+C\right)^3\right).
\end{align}$$
This was just scratch work. Now, "out of the blue", consider the function $t\mapsto \sqrt{\dfrac{8t^6}{27}}$ (I just picked $C=0$. The choice of $C$ depends on the I.V.P., you can solve the general case with $y=y_0$ if you wish - here I'm considering $y_0=0$).

Comment: Verify that it satisfies the D.E.. Note that this function can be rewritten as $t\mapsto \alpha\left|t^3\right|$, where $\alpha=\sqrt{\dfrac{8}{27}}$. It isn't differentiable at the origin, but you can glue an equilibrium solution (in this case (again, depending on the IVP) the null function) to the "positive part" of the function, thus extending the solution to the real line. Cleaning up a bit, you would consider $t\mapsto \begin{cases} 0, &\text{if }t\leq0\\ \alpha\left|t^3\right|, &\text{if }t>0\end{cases}$. This function is differentiable (check it).

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838229/deciding-whether-solution-to-ode-is-unique/838263#838263).

Comment: @GitGud. Cheers!

Comment: If the DE has a point where it fails to be Lipschitz then uniqueness could fail and piecewise combination of solutions could be made... see this Wiki [Singular solutions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_solution)